# Having trouble creating a certain pattern

Tags: c#

Hey guys I am having trouble creating a certain type of shape in C# that is meant to look like this with the two triangle patterns

```
*****
****
***
**
*
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I have managed to create one inverted right triangle pattern but I cant seem to figure out how to create a right triangle star pattern beneath it.

Here is the code I managed to make:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Hello_Word
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int val = 5;
            int i, j, k;
            for (i = 1; i <= val; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= val - i; j++)
                {
                    // Console.Write(" ");  
                }
                for (k = 1; k <= j; k++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: easy as pie! `for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) Console.WriteLine(new string('*', i));` and then `for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) Console.WriteLine(new string('*', i));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty simple homework question - hope you enjoy this solution:

```
using System;

class Program {
    const Int32 maxTriangleSize = 5;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        for (Int32 i = maxTriangleSize - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Console.WriteLine(new String('*', i + 1));
        }

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < maxTriangleSize; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(new String('*', i + 1));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already know how to print all the lines from widest to narrowest. You just want to do the the same, but backwards - start narrow, and print wide:

```
for (i = val; i >= 1; i--)
```

How to use this is up to you. I would put the inner part of the loop in a function, so main would become:

```
for (i = 1; i <= val; i++) printLine(i,val);
for (i = val; i >= 1; i--) printLine(i,val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify any REQUIREMENTS.  Where does it say you can't use just a bunch of WriteLine() calls?

```
Console.WriteLine("*****");
Console.WriteLine("****");
Console.WriteLine("***");
Console.WriteLine("**");
Console.WriteLine("*");
Console.WriteLine("*");
Console.WriteLine("**");
Console.WriteLine("***");
Console.WriteLine("****");
Console.WriteLine("*****");
```

Must you use a For loop?  How about While loops instead? Etc...

With that in mind, here's a RECURSIVE solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RecursiveTriangle(5);         
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void RecursiveTriangle(int width)
{
    if (width > 0)
    {
        string row = new string('*', width);
        Console.WriteLine(row);
        RecursiveTriangle(--width);
        Console.WriteLine(row);
    }
}
```

A variant:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RecursiveTriangle(new String('*', 5));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void RecursiveTriangle(string row)
{
    if (row.Length > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row);
        RecursiveTriangle(row.Substring(0, row.Length - 1));
        Console.WriteLine(row);
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

**If there are restraints or requirements, be sure to post those as well next time.**

Answer (score 0):

As the number of stars per row are decreasing by a constant count, you can print them together. You can start with incrementing the numbers and then use another loop decrementing the counter.
I've tested the below code and it seems to work fine.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int val = 5;
            for (int m = val; m > 0; m--)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new string('*', m));
            }
            for (int n = 1; n <= 5; n++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new string('*', n));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```